# how to get Android SDK Command-line Tools other version(not latest)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-doctor

I'm using Java 1.8 OpenJDK.

I assume I need to use Android SDK Command-line Tools 8. not latest.
to pass all flutter doctor thing.

Does anyone know how I can get it?

I tried install latest version but the flutter doctor Android license stuff show me the java compile error.

Comment: Has your problem been resolved? Please, if so, mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You can download custom version of `Android SDK Command-line Tools` with `Android Studio` by go to `SDK Tools` and check option `Show Package Details` like this:

[image]